# Views using the scene dock not replicating itself in a horizontal scroll view

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, horizontalscrollview

I am designing a horizontal scroll view in one of my pages. I am trying to inflate it with a number of views depending upon a particular array count.I achieved this programmatically using the following code.

```
override func viewDidLoad()

    {
        super.viewDidLoad()





        let viewcount = 15
        scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(110*CGFloat(viewcount), hrzntlscrl.frame.height)



        for var i = 0; i < viewcount; i++
        {

            let viewnew = UIView(frame: CGRectMake( hrzntlscrl.frame.origin.x+110*CGFloat(i), 0, 100.0, hrzntlscrl.frame.height))
            viewnew.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
            imagevieww = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 10, 100.0, 50))
            imagevieww.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
            viewnew.addSubview(imagevieww)

            scrollview.addSubview(viewnew)
        }



    }
```

The o/p comes as a total of 15 views in my scroll view -

[image]

But I wanted tried to use the scene dock facility of xcode to create a standard view to represent my views to be added to the scroll view -

[image]

. And I modified my code as -

```
override func viewDidLoad()

    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

      tableview.delegate = self
        tableview.dataSource = self



        let viewcount = 15
        scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(110*CGFloat(viewcount), hrzntlscrl.frame.height)

        for var i = 0; i < viewcount; i++
        {

            print(i)
                 scrollview.addSubview(myownview)
//my ownview is the reference outlet of my view in the dock as   @IBOutlet var myownview: UIView!

            myownview.frame.origin.x = 110*CGFloat(i)
        }



    }
```

and the o/p comes as only 1 view added to the end of the scroll view. The view didn't copy itself -

[image]

So what mistake am I doing. And what can be my alternative to my programmatic creation of view apart from view in scene dock.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing the same instance of `myownview` every time you call `scrollview.addSubview(myownview)`.

Make `myownview` a subclass of `UIView` and instantiate a new instance of it in every cycle of you for loop.

Something like:

```
for var i = 0; i < viewcount; i++ {
    let myownview = MyOwnCustomView()

    // further initialization

    scrollview.addSubview(myownview)
}
```